# Same method for all buttons(Dialing method)

Tags: android

I am creating a phonebook app, where phonenumbers are already loaded in it.![layout having name and numbers.i defined numbers already.][1] 
app image is in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPbOa.jpg

This is the xml file.

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tushar.ruphonedirectory15.ACCE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">





<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffb14d"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/press"
        android:textColor="#ffff2c2e"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView79" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/sovapoti"
        android:id="@+id/textView73"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/acce1"
        android:id="@+id/textView74"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView73"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

       />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac1"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView74"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac2"
        android:id="@+id/button64"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/profesor"
        android:id="@+id/textView75"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button64"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/acce2"
        android:id="@+id/textView76"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView75"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac3"
        android:id="@+id/button65"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView76"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/acce3"
        android:id="@+id/textView77"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button66"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac4"
        android:id="@+id/button66"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button65"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac5"
        android:id="@+id/button67"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView77" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/acce4"
        android:id="@+id/textView78"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button68"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff4cd6ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ac6"
        android:id="@+id/button68"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button67"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/make"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

I had to write the java code to dial this numbers.But the problem is i had to write java code for each numbers and each buttons.which makes the java code lengthy.java codes are given below.so is there any way to use the same method (dialing) for all buttons.so the java code can be lessened.phone numbers are saved in values>string.

```html
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ACCE extends ActionBarActivity {
        Button a1;
    Button a2;
    Button a3;
    Button a4;
    Button a5;
    Button a6;
    Button a7;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acce);
        a1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        a2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button64);
        a3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button65);
        a4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button66);
        a5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button67);
        a6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button68);
        a7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button69);

   a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m1();
            }
        });
        a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m2();
            }
        });
        a3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               m3();
            }
        });
        a4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m4();
            }
        });
        a5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m5 ();
            }
        });
        a6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m6 ();
            }
        });
        a7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m7 ();
            }
        });


protected void m1() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0721711106"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void m2() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0721810009"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void m3() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:01191536769"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void m4() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0721772307"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
    protected void m5() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:01914254694"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void m6() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0721750498"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void m7() {
        Log.i("Make call", "");

        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:01712255636"));

        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ACCE.this,
                    "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a listview and click listener for each item.tag your number on each item.then handle your code inside listview.onItemClickListener()

Comment: sorry i cant understand ,can you specify more.i am a beginner so consider it,please.and thank you

Comment: your phone book app should use a listview.manually writing thousands of button is not good. see sample listview -  https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-listview-example-with-custom-adapter/

Comment: Thank you rasel...are you from bangladesh?? can i conatact you ??can we be friends on facebook??আর আপনাকে অশেষ ধন্যবাদ

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to define for each button? Just do it like this

```
a1.setOnClickListener(this);
a2.setOnClickListener(this);
.....
a7.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now make your class implement OnClickListener and define Overridden onClick().
There you will get events for all click.

Comment: I created a sample project by implementing your codes...plz download a copy from here..again thank you https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4geJM64QbSVNm1nUGlxM216YVk/view?usp=sharing